# Namespace and execution sequence in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to understand namespace and  execution sequence in Python

I wrote a sample code:

```
def some_func():
    print("A")
    def some_inner_func():
        print("B")
    some_inner_func()
some_func()
print("C")
```

The result is

```
A
B
C
```

Why the output is A B C not B A C ?
Per my understanding, first `some_inner_func()` is called then `some_func()` and at last `print("C")`.

Please help me with this simple puzzle.

Comment: As soon as you call `some_func`, the first `print` statement (`print("A")`) will be executed.

Comment: `some_inner_func` *doesn't even exist* until a call to `some_func` is in progress.

Comment: Thanks @jasonharper That's the point I want to figure out. But a little more concern, what's the detail mean of 'exist' here in Python? Will Python create a namesapce for  `some_inner_func()`  when I define `some_func()` but not call it?   Sorry, I am beginner in Python.

Comment: The local variables of a function generally only exist for the duration of a call to that function (the exception is variables accessed by a nested function, whose lifetime is extended for as long as any call to the nested function is possible, but that's not relevant here).  A namespace containing `some_inner_func` comes into existence whenever `some_func()` is called, and vanishes after the call finishes.

Comment: @jasonharper Wow, that's cool, thanks for the detail explanation. Please kindly move your comment to below reply. I'll mark it.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you call `some_func()` first, and in `some_func` you `print('A')` before you call `some_inner_func`, that's why it prints out `A` and then `B`

If you want it to be in order of `B A C` then you just need to change where you put the `print('A')` in `some_func`

```
def some_func():
    def some_inner_func():
        print("B")
    some_inner_func()
    print("A")
some_func()
print("C")
```

Comment: Thanks , I was told the Python is interpreted line by line.  Seems when I define the function `some_func():` , I must also call it later, otherwise even I define any sub function and call the sub function  directly in `some_func()` I will not print any thing. Just one more question, will Python create a namesapce for  `some_inner_func()`  when I define `some_func()` but not call it?